# Evaluating this generalised integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, integral-equations

I have the following integral

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\exp \left(a u^2+b v^2+c u v\right) \; dvdu,$$

which returns the following solution:

$$\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{4 a b-c^2}}.$$

I would like to generalise the integral to define the following function:

$$f[x, y] := \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\exp \left(a u^2+b v^2+c u v\right) u^x v^y\; dvdu,$$

which Mathematica generates a solution to in terms of Hypergeometric functions but crucially it is a function of `x` and `y`. I would like to use this function for a range of different `x` and `y`, i.e.

```
Table[f[x,y], {x,0,10}, {y,0,10}]
```

As a cross check, I would like to get a consistent result when $x=y=0$. The issue is that when I try to evaluate `f[0,0]`, I get Indeterminate due to a `0 ComplexInfinity`. I.e. this doesn't reproduce the result at the top. A same issue occurs for `f[0,2]`.

Is there a fix to this? Can I define cases where it breaks?

Comment: Can you use `Limit` to find the value at zero?

Comment: @mikado, I would like to use the function for higher values of `x` and `y`. I get a complex infinity with x=0 and y=2 too

Comment: @Sid  I get a real result like this: ```With[{x = 0, y = 2},   Integrate[Exp[a u^2 + b v^2 + c u v] u^x v^y, {v, -∞, ∞}, {u, -∞, ∞}]]
```

Comment: Looks like: $$\fbox{$\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{-a} \sqrt{-b} \sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{4 a b}}}\text{ if }b<0\land a<0\land c^2 \Re\left(\frac{1}{a b}\right)<4$}$$

Comment: @flinty yes it works when you explicitly determine it as you have. If you however find the general expression to `f[x_, y_]` for `u^x v^y` (which Mathematica can handle) then determine `f[0,2]`, I get a `Indeterminate`. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, I added some extra information to the OP. Mathematica can handle different integrands, but I want to reproduce the result from the more general function `f[x,y]` for different values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: `Integrate[
 Exp[a*u^2 + b*v^2 + c*u*v]*v^2, {u, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}]` results in `ConditionalExpression[-((
  4 a Sqrt[-b] Sqrt[-4 a + c^2/b] \[Pi])/(-4 a b + c^2)^2), 
 Re[a - c^2/(4 b)] < 0]` which is not true (see at the result of `Plot3D[Exp[2*u^2 + 1*v^2 + 2*u*v]*v^2, {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}]`). Submit a report to Wolfram Technical Support.

Answer (score 3):

**modified answer (11.04.2021)**

(Thanks @DanielLichtblau for his helpful comment)

Here my ideas to make it work:

Mathematica evaluates the first  integral to

```
Integrate[Exp[a u^2 + b v^2 +c u v], {v, -∞,∞}, {u, -∞, ∞},Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c}, Reals] ]
(*ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi])/(Sqrt[-b]Sqrt[-4 a + c^2/b]),
4 a b^2 < b c^2] *)
```

result is correct but the condition is **wrong**!

**stepwise integration**

Assuming `a!=0` the integral

`Integrate[Exp[a (u + c/(2 a) v)^2 ]Exp[a (b/a - (c/(2 a))^2) v ^2 ] , {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {v, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` is transformed to

```
Integrate[Integrate[Exp[a (u + c/(2 a)v)^2], {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]} ] Exp[a (b/a - (c/(2 a))^2) v^2], {v, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`
(* ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi])/(Sqrt[-a]Sqrt[-4 b + c^2/a]), Re[a] < 0 && Re[c^2/a] > 4 Re[b]]*)
```

with **correct conditions** `a<0 && c^2< 4 a b`

Take these condition for the general case

```
int = Function[{x, y}, 
Evaluate@Integrate[Exp[a u^2 + b v^2 + c u v] u^x v^y, {v, -∞, ∞}, {u, -∞, ∞}, 
Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c}, Reals], a<0,c^2< 4 a b}]]
```

These evaluate the mentioned cases as expected

```
Limit[int[x, y], {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
(*ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi])/(Sqrt[-a] Sqrt[-b] Sqrt[4 - c^2/(a b)]), c <0]*)     

int[0,2]
(*ConditionalExpression[(a \[Pi])/(2 (-a)^(3/2) Sqrt[-b] b (1 - c^2/(4 ab))^(3/2)), c < 0]*)
```

Comment: -1. Your statement  "First integral only converges if  `4 a^2 b < a c^2`" is ungrounded and does not correspond to reality: put `a=1;b=1;c=3`, then `NIntegrate[Exp[1*u^2 + 1*v^2 + 3*u*v], {u, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10}]` results in `5.63016*10^213`..Also see `Plot3D[Exp[u^2 + v^2 + 3*u*v]*v^2, {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}]`. Your mistake consists in the following. In the case `a=1;b=1;c=3`
 the integrand takes big valuea in the first and third quadrants and approaches zero in the second and fourth quadrants.  In any case, the integrand is positive. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 The condition is well grounded it we trust Mathematicas Integrate function.  `Integrate[
 Exp[a u^2 + b v^2 + 
   c u v], {v, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {u, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]}]` . If not there is nothing left from this question to discuss about. By the way your "scoring" is dispensable...

Comment: A correct set of conditions would be `{a<0,b<0,c^2<4*a*b}`. This implies the condition provided by `Integrate`, but not the other way around. This mishap notwithstanding, the method is otherwise sound. Which is to my surprise, since I did not expect a result that would be amenable to `Limit`. But I'd add assumptions such as `x,y>-1` to simplify things.

Comment: I wonder the upvotes for the wrong answer https://www.dropbox.com/s/10sed1oaee273ac/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-04-10%2018.19.11.png?dl=0.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Thank you for your helpful comment. The condition `4 a^2 b < a c^2 ` Mathematica provides after `Integrate[
 Exp[a u^2 + b v^2 + 
   c u v], {v, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {u, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c}, Reals] }]` is wrong!  If I integrate step by step Mathematica creates two conditions `a<=0&&c^2 < 4 a^2 b`

Comment: To state the obvious, there are up votes because several people think this answer is useful. Myself among them.